# Where can I locate legacy hashes for older minor releases?

Tags: 14.04, hash

I need md5sum or sha1sum hashes for version Ubuntu 14.04.3 Can someone please help me locate them?

Comment: Hashes for Ubuntu? Ubuntu doesn't need any user-supplied hashes for its installation or operation. Are you maybe looking for the checksums of the Ubuntu installation images?

Comment: @Mohamed Ali It's probably a little late now, but I was looking for the older sums as well, when I found: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases Using this link you can traverse and find any old hash you'll need. I don't have enough xp here to vote to re-open the case, but decided to put this as a comment at least in case it can help others in the future!

Answer (score 2):

If you are taking about the various [checksum hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) (md5, sha1, sha256, ...), you can find the information you are looking for in the Ubuntu 14.04.3 release [page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/)